Feature selector on a pricing component
Currently on our website we has something like this:
You can

Either chose the main product we sell or an additional feature
You can select your contract duration, and
Then there's a CTA in the the pricing cards.

We are adding a new feature which can also be selected here. I came up with this idea:

If they click on Feature 2 or 3 this changes to following:

I got a requirement to come up with a few more variations of how to implement this new feature.
Could you suggest some ideas/other elements that could be used instead? Thanks!

You can’t just delegate the question you’ve been asked to this community. Can you instead tell what’s wrong with the current examples, why there is a need for more/better ideas?

I have a question about the features. Are they mutually exclusive? Because if they are not, I think is going to be very busy (visually) on that selection.
Also I'm assuming that the packages are different each one of them, the features that the company is offering are new for the clients, and you want to verify if the clients want to add them or not. I'm going to put an example as I understood the problem.
Let's say that Netflix has its different packages to stream content, package 1: the basic, package 2: up to three devices, and package 3: up to five devices, and the additional features are channels that you can't add to the current packages; feature 1: MGM+, feature 2: Star+. If this is your case you can add checks to each one of the cards to see how each package changes based on the add-ons selected. However if that's not close to your use case I don't see why you want to have three different sections where the user's attention will be drawn. That's the reason I asked if the features were mutually exclusive.

Happy designs, ‍

I think there are a couple of problems

The component used is wrong
The added features do not highlight their qualities

The component used is a Segmented control:

Segmented control is used to pick one choice from a linear set of closely related choices, and immediately apply that selection.

And this is not the function that is sought, on the contrary, each new feature is an addition to the main feature, so I understand that they can be selected together.
I would look for more contrasting options to better understand the functionality and from there decide which is the best design.
Function:

There is an existing feature
There are other features visible
The features can be selected together with the main one

I would try to make it clear that there is a fixed feature separate from the selectable options, which can be activated independently and deactivated with the second click.

